# Wind resistance on moving body

Tags: drag, relative-motion

Suppose that a vehicle is traveling 60 km/h north, and the wind speed is also 60 km/h going the same direction, would there be wind resistance, and to what extent? Also, if I put my hand outside the window, would it feel as though the car was not moving?

Comment: Yes, there would be wind resistance because the speed of the wind couldn't be the same near the ground as higher up. Right at the surface the windspeed has to be zero and there is a gradient towards the max. windspeed at some height.

Comment: Let's idealize this. A wind speed gradient is caused near the ground by viscosity, or friction. Assume the "vehicle" is a thrown rock not near the ground. It travels parallel to uniformly moving air, at the same speed as the air. There would be no wind resistance. An ant on the rock would not feel the air moving. Of course, the rock would then follow a parabolic trajectory. It would no longer be traveling in the same direction as the air. There would be wind resistance. The ant would feel wind.